# Can Spring-Data-Cassandra support Specification interface?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

Can Spring-Data-Cassandra support Specification interface?

If yes, can you please give me a simple example.

Thanks.

Comment: No, there's no `Specification` support in Spring Data for Apache Cassandra.

Comment: @mp911de thx. that is what I though.

Comment: Generally, there's not Specification API support for NoSQL.